# H264 to jpeg FFMPEG decoding/encoding in C

Tags: c, ffmpeg, decode, h.264

I'm trying to write a script in C to decode H264 frames and then encode them to jpeg/png format, frame-by-frame.

I'm going off of the tutorials given in the official [decoder](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/release/4.4/doc/examples/decode_video.c) and [encoder](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/release/4.4/doc/examples/encode_video.c) examples, but with a decoder type of AV_CODEC_ID_H264 and an encoder type AV_CODEC_ID_MJPEG, the files I am saving seem to be unreadable. Am I using the incorrect codecs?

Comment: Not clear what _"decode H264 frames"_ means here exactly (_eg:_are you extracting them from an MP4 file? Or is your input actually one long H264 file, and if so how do you separate a single frame to encode as image?)... If this was my problem and I was still learning I would do this: **(1)** Use the FFmpeg commandline version to first encode some single JPG or PNG image into H264. Now there is only one frame to test with in your C/C++ code. **(2)** Research how to convert that input of H264  into a PNG output. The process is to convert H264 into AVFrame data then write such data out as PNG.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I knew that the decoded frame was correct since I saved it and used FFMPEG in the command line to create a PNG. I ended up going with the following method: using swsformat to convert the decoded H264 frame to RGB, and then loading it into an OpenCV::Mat.

Comment: Codecs are correct, maybe an issue how U setup the encoder